# IIS rewritten rule to redirect a url

Tags: redirect, iis

I have a SSL website that I want to redirect all calls to a different SSL site including POST data.
After several attempts, no success. Any suggestions
This is what I have so far.

```
<rule name="Redirect url" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost"   appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Read FRT to learn what might be wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: The rule works perfectly on my side. Please ensure the orginal and target website are using different host name in binding host header. Besides, please check your rewrite rule order list to ensure the rule won't be bypassed by other rule. Thirdly, please try to clean browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the rule works.

The web site at https://localhost is a MVC ASP.NET app. It has a controller and action. i.e /Application/Action
I think the issue is with the MVC routing. 
Using Fiddler I see the incoming POST to the expected URL (/Application/Action) and posted data with a 301 result.
Then then next URL I see is / instead of the expected URL (/Application/Action) with 200 result.
I am at a loss as to why the URL is /  instead of /Application/Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also need to append request URI in the end of target URL, please modify the rule like this.

```
<rule name="Redirect url" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```